# When will the latest Firefox be available on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, firefox

2023-11-27_Mon_10:26:33

Hi,

I am getting very tired of Firefox-ESR.  It is simply NOT modern enough to keep up with many of today's websites.  Examples: YouTube, Amazon, Google Maps, ...  My main computer at home is an RPi 4B and Firefox-ESR on that machine is just too slow for some websites even when they do work.

Yes, I could use Chromium and sometimes I must.  **HOWEVER  I  DO  NOT  TRUST  CHROMIUM.  (And neither should you.)**  It's a stated goal of that "free" browser to learn stuff about you to sell your information to advertisers and God-only-knows what other snoops or governments or ....  Some US states are now trying to use browsing data to criminalize women's access to medical care IN OTHER STATES.  Do I have to have to make it more clear than that?

To get around Firefox-ESR's ancient or failed rendering of some web pages I must use Chromium.  For example, if I want to find items to buy on Amazon then I pick out the items using Chromium (because Firefox-ESR really sucks on Amazon) and then I switch over to Firefox-ESR to actually purchase said items.  To watch any video on YouTube I use Chromium but I will not log in because I don't want Chromium to track my interests, therefore, say, I can't write comments about videos, etc.  I will NEVER use Chromium to do banking, use my credit card, look at medical or health issues, etc.  Some websites work on my 4B under Firefox-ESR but they are just too slow, an example being the NY Times; maybe the RPi 5 I have on order will fix that.  Maybe.

So, when are we Raspbian users going to get our hands on the latest stable release of Firefox, *NOT* SOME FOSSILIZED VERSION OF FIREFOX LIKE -ESR?

Or do we have to go to some other Linux distro entirely?  If so then please tell us which one.

Thank you.

Comment: I downvoted your post because more than half of the text is irrelevant to the question ... both, second and third paragraph do not contain anything that actually relates to the question ... we do not need to know your opinion about chromium and we do not need to know how you use the two browsers together

Comment: if you're still using `Raspbian` then you may need to update to a newer operating system - `Firefox-ESR on that machine is just too slow` - the latest Firefox won't help speed issues - I'm interested to know, which version of Firefox-ESR your pi runs

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Raspberry Pi OS based on Debian Bookworm allows to to select Firefox or Chromium on setup. If you select Firefox the latest release branch of Firefox (not ESR) becomes your default browser. Firefox 119.0 is the current version.

Comment: except firefox 120.0 is the actual current version :p